# Usage of abolish coercion functions

Tags: vim

I'm using vim-abolish plugin for coercion and wanted to try abolish functions for case changing in substitution eg.:

```
:s#FOO_FOO#\=Abolish.dashcase(\1)#
```

I've checked docs but there is no info about using it from plugin functions. How can i make them available in vim? Seems like they are almost ready to use here, but i don't know how to make it:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish/blob/master/plugin/abolish.vim

Answer (score 2):

`\1` can only be used in a regular substitution. Since you have opted for an expression, you must use `:help submatch()`:

```
:s#FOO_FOO#\=Abolish.dashcase(submatch(<your number here>))#
```

See `:help sub-replace-special`.